# NSLOOKUP confusion: Where is it getting its information locally?

Tags: linux, dns, nslookup

I perform `nslookup` on a non-local address, say Google. On my machine (running Ubuntu 12.10), I get this as a result:

```
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.37.52
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.37.48
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.37.49
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.37.50
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 173.194.37.51
```

I'm trying to understand this. I assume the list of addresses under "Non-authoritative answer" are all of the possible addresses that google.com is using, but why is it listing my local host information at the top? Also, is `nslookup` querying a local machine, or only the DNS server?

I was looking at [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/using-nslookup-dns-server-diagnosis.html) link to explain `nslookup`, but it's for Windows and I'm not sure that I understand what they're doing there.

I've also consulted the `man` pages, but those just tell me how to use `nslookup`, not any of the "theory" behind it. Would somebody mind explaining exactly where `nslookup` queries, preferably using an example, in order?

I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It queries wherever the appropriate values in `/etc/resolv.conf` tell it to. In this case it is pointing to the local machine, which is most likely acting as a caching or proxy DNS server. Use `netstat` to find out which program is listening on port 53.

Comment: Okay, my `/etc/resolv.conf` file only has `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in it, so I guess `nslookup` checks the first thing in `/etc/resolv.conf` before checking the remote DNS server?

Comment: It *always* checks the appropriate values in `resolv.conf`.